# Python 3 with Flask runtime error: "AttributeError: module 'hmac' has no attribute 'digest'" on Linux but not Windows

Tags: python-3.x, flask, hmac

Error message "AttributeError: module 'hmac' has no attribute 'digest'" is being thrown on my python3 flask+connexion server, when used on my Ubuntu VPS, but not my Windows 10 PC. Both are using Python3, and I've reimaged the VPS from CentOS, in case I'd made some config error.

I'm trying to use the digest method of Python3's inbuilt hmac module (note that Python2 hmac doesn't have digest), and have upgraded python and pip.
I'm starting to wonder if flask is overriding hmac with it's own implementation, but I'm not sure how this would be affected by OS. Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: can you try `print(sys.version)` before you call the `digest()` method to see if the expected version is being used?

Comment: First checks would be `which python` and `python --version`

Comment: I'm launching using "python3.5 server.py" - output of print(sys.version) is "
3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]"

Comment: [module-level hmac.digest()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hmac.html#hmac.digest) is new in 3.7. So it's not available in 3.5. In 3.5 you can the [digest method of HMAC object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hmac.html#hmac.HMAC.digest). I would guess on Windows you have the latest 3.7 installed.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, and thanks @buran, that was the issue! I've fixed it now, by creating an HMAC object, as detailed in your link, then calling digest() on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment as answer, so that the question is properly answered. As it become clear OP uses different python3 versions.

> [module-level hmac.digest()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hmac.html#hmac.digest) is new in 3.7. So it's not available
>   in 3.5. In 3.5 you can the [digest method of HMAC object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hmac.html#hmac.HMAC.digest). I would
>   guess on Windows you have the latest 3.7 installed.